# simple bash while loop creates an unwanted file named 0

Tags: bash

For some inexplicable reason, when I run the following code (minimalized, obviously) a file called "0" is created.    Could somebody please explain why this happens, and how to avoid it?     Thanks very much

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 > 0 ] 
    do
        exit
    done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`> 0` redirects to a file named `0`. Note `> something` or similar syntax [does not have to be at the end](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690). The file will be created even if the command being redirected doesn't make sense. In your case the command is `[ 1 ]` and it's syntactically valid: it checks if `1` is a non-empty string.

You probably meant `[ 1 -gt 0 ]`. See `help [` and `help test | less`.

Comment: You can still use `\<` and `\>` for string comparison.

Comment: Or use double brackets IE `[[ 1 :operator: 0 ]]` without the escapes where operator is `>` or `<`. Seems that `>=` and `<=` are invalid so the usual `-ge` and `-le` should be used in those cases.

Comment: @Jim although it's syntactically legal, it's a *string* comparison i.e. a test of lexical order (try `[[ 2 > 11 ]]` for example) - so not the same as `-gt `.

Comment: @steeldriver Ah good catch!! I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the correction.